# An original criterion for integrable function

Tags: integration, functions

I came up with the following exercise :

Let $f$ be a $\mathscr{C}^{1}$ and positive function in $\left[1,+\infty\right[$ such as $f\left(1\right)=1$.

We suppose that
$$
\frac{xf'\left(x\right)}{f\left(x\right)}\underset{x \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow} \alpha
$$
where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

$(i)$ Find the limit of $\displaystyle \text{ }\frac{\ln\left(f\left(x\right)\right)}{\ln\left(x\right)}$ when $x \rightarrow +\infty$

$(ii)$ Deduce that if $\alpha<-1$, $f$ is integrable in $\left[1,+\infty\right[$.

*What I have done :*

I used that
$$
\int_{1}^{x}t\frac{f'\left(t\right)}{f\left(t\right)}\text{d}t=\left[t\ln\left(f\left(t\right)\right)\right]^{x}_{1}-\int_{1}^{x}\ln\left(f\left(t\right)\right)\text{d}t=x\ln\left(f\left(x\right)\right)-\int_{1}^{x}\ln\left(f\left(t\right)\right)\text{d}t
$$
But well doesn't work well ... Do you guys have suggestions ?

Comment: If we knew that $\;f(x)\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\infty\;$ , then (i) is just tje given limit **after** doing L'Hospital...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not $f(x)\rightarrow\infty$, because $\ln x\rightarrow\infty$, L'Hopital rule still applies, look at this [link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule). So the limit is still $\alpha$.

For the second question. Since $\alpha<-1$, pick an $\epsilon>0$ such that $\alpha+1+\epsilon<0$, then there exists some $M>0$ such that $|\ln(f(x))/\ln x-\alpha|<\epsilon$, so $\dfrac{\ln f(x)}{\ln x}<\alpha+\epsilon$, or $\ln f(x)<(\alpha+\epsilon)\ln x$ for all $x\geq M$. Taking exponential both sides we get $f(x)<x^{\alpha+\epsilon}$ for all $x\geq M$. Now the integral $\displaystyle\int_{M}^{\infty}x^{\alpha+\epsilon}dx$ converges.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $\alpha \neq 0$, we have $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\sim \frac{\alpha}{x}$. Since the function $x \mapsto \dfrac{\alpha}{x}$ is positive (or negative if $\alpha<0$) and not integrable on $[1,+\infty[$, we have

$$
\int_1^x \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)} \mathrm{d}t \sim \int_1^x \frac{\alpha}{t}\mathrm{d}t,
$$

i.e.

$$
\ln{f(x)}\sim\alpha \ln{x}.
$$

That answers (i).

Comment: Wow nice one thanks. That was the point i wanted to use with this $f'(t)/f(t)$. Thanks !

Comment: I think you mean integrable.

Comment: @AlexVong : no. when two functions $f$ and $g$ are positive and **not integrable**, if $f(x) \sim_{+\infty} g(x)$ then $\int_0^x f(t) \mathrm{d}t \sim \int_0^x g(t) \mathrm{d}t$. This is not true anymore when they are integrable (indeed, the two integrals converge and may converge to different limits).

Comment: @tristan OK I understand now. By not integrable, you mean the improper integrals do not exists.

Comment: @AlexVong Indeed, my bad. I'm French and I assumed saying a function is not integrable would have the same meaning in English, but I was wrong.

Comment: @tristan I am also not a native speaker. I think your usage is correct, just less common.